# Ansible parse value from stdsout

Tags: parsing, ansible

Im runnning a ansible playbook with some commands to a networkdevice (juniper) to check status.
The output look like this:

```
"Monitor Failure codes:", 
            "    CS  Cold Sync monitoring        FL  Fabric Connection monitoring", 
            "    GR  GRES monitoring             HW  Hardware monitoring", 
            "    IF  Interface monitoring        IP  IP monitoring", 
            "    LB  Loopback monitoring         MB  Mbuf monitoring", 
            "    NH  Nexthop monitoring          NP  NPC monitoring              ", 
            "    SP  SPU monitoring              SM  Schedule monitoring", 
            "    CF  Config Sync monitoring", 
            " ", 
            "Cluster ID: 1", 
            "Node   Priority Status         Preempt Manual   Monitor-failures", 
            "", 
            "Redundancy group: 0 , Failover count: 0", 
            "node0  1       secondary      no      no       None           ", 
            "node1  125       primary        no      no       None           ",
            "", 
            "Redundancy group: 1 , Failover count: 0", 
            "node0  1       secondary      yes     no       None           ", 
            "node1  125       primary        yes     no       None"
```

I want to filter and then do some checks on the segments under Redundancy group: 0 and 1 (the other port is of no intrest. I cant figure out the best way to parse them out, write filter plugin? Or just regexp? In the best of world i would like to sepearate redundacy group 0 and 1 so i can check them separatly. But thats not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need some complex processing, then yes – write a filter plugin.

But some basic processing can be done with regular expressions and other filters, see this example:

```
- debug:
    msg: "Name={{ node_name }}, val1={{ node_val_1 }}"
  vars:
    node_name: "{{ item.split()[0] }}"
    node_val_1: "{{ item.split()[1] }}"
    regexp: '^Redundancy group: 0[\s\S]+?^$'
    new_line: "\n"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ node_name }}"
  with_items: >
              {{ (
                  (mylines | join(new_line) + new_line)
                  | regex_search(regexp, multiline=true)
                 ).splitlines()[1:] }}
```

This searches for range of lines starting with `Redundancy group: 0` and ending with empty line, then feed this lines into looped `debug` module.

Comment: Hmm, i just did a copy/paste, when i excecute the playbook i get this error.
fatal: [testnode.1]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "'mylines' is undefined"
}

i save the output from the command with:

register: status

Im not really that familar with this so i tried to replace mylines with status, then i got 
 
{
    "msg": "'None' has no attribute 'splitlines'"
}

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't guess your variable name...

Comment: Yeah ofc you could not :), i posted the comment half done.

Comment: Debug `status` first. You should have something like `status.stdout` or something.

Comment: Excellent, now it works :)